# SQL - Join tables where first table has a value that must fall within the range specified in the second

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a resultset that looks something like:

```
[DateField ][Hour][Value]
 2014-10-01  1     200    
 2014-10-01  2     600
```

I need to add a couple of additional columns from another table like:

```
[DateField ][Hour][Value][T2Value1][T2Value2]
 2014-10-01  1     200    Off       5
 2014-10-01  2     600    Off       7
```

I need the T2Value1 and T2Value2 from Table 2 below if the Value field from Table 1 falls between the RangeValue1 and RangeValue2 of Table 2.

```
[Id][T2Value1][T2Value2][RangeValue1][RangeValue2]
 1   Off       5         1            500
 2   Off       7         501          1000
```

I've started to query

```
select datefield, hour, value, t2value1, t2value2 from
(
    -- inner query that returns datefield, hour, value
) Table1, Table2
```

but don't know where to take it from here. Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: The condition on the join clause can be complex as any condition on a where clause thus you can put here a range condition much like you can do in a where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple join should get you what you need.  The on condition is a little more complicated than normal, but not much.

```
select t1.DateField, t1.Hour, t2.t2value1, t2.t2value2
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.RangeValue1 <= t1.Value and t1.Value <= t2.RangeValue2
```

Comment: just a tip use `A <= Value < B` instead of `A <= Value <= B` to avoid intersecting ranges at any point

Comment: @jean Except, given his example data, the ranges are non-overlapping and inclusive, thus the =.

Answer (score 2):

See this simple example:

```
declare @Values as table
(
 Name varchar(10) not null
,Value int not null
)

declare @Ranges as table
(
 Grade char(1) not null
,v0 int not null
,v1 int not null
)

insert into @Values
values
 ('Albert', 33)
,('Bob', 133)
,('Carl', 233)

insert into @Ranges
values
 ('A',0,100)
,('B',100,200)
,('C',200,300)

select * from @Values v
join @Ranges r on r.v0 <= v.Value and v.Value < r.v1
```

As you can see it's ok to put some more complex condition on the join clause, in this case a range condition

it results in:

```
Name       Value       Grade v0          v1
---------- ----------- ----- ----------- -----------
Albert     33          A     0           100
Bob        133         B     100         200
Carl       233         C     200         300
```